# AngularJS Filter with apply button and without autocomplete

Tags: javascript, angularjs, autocomplete, pug

I need a filter with an "Apply" button and without autocomplete. I can't do that. Here's my basic code, with autocomplete (I don't want it) and without button (I want this).

I'm using Jade.

search.jade

```
input(type="text", ng-model="buscador.id", placeholder="Ejemplo: 111")
```

listmagazines.jade

```
.col-xlg-25.col-sm-3.col-xs-3.col-xxs-6(ng-repeat="magazine in magazines|filter:buscador")
```

app.js It has a lot of items, I'll put just three.

```
var app = angular.module("appBuscador", []);

app.factory("revistas", function(){
  return{
    "revistasNumeros":[
    {
      id: 97,
      titulo: "Nº97",
      img: "pdf97.jpg",
      descarga: "",
      url: "http://www.mapfre.com/fundacion/html/revistas/gerencia/n097/index.html"
    },
    {
      id: 98,
      titulo: "Nº98",
      img: "pdf98.jpg",
      descarga: "",
      url: "http://www.mapfre.com/fundacion/html/revistas/gerencia/n098/index.html"
    },
    {
      id: 99,
      titulo: "Nº99",
      img: "pdfdefault.jpg",
      descarga: "",
      url: "http://www.mapfre.com/fundacion/html/revistas/gerencia/n099/index.html"
    }
    ]
  }
})
```

controller.js

```
app.controller("revistasController", function($scope,revistas){
  $scope.magazines = revistas.revistasNumeros;
})
```

Thank you.

--------------------- SORRY I CAN'T ADD AN ANSWER I'M BANNED

I found the solution:

search.jade (add a  button)

```
input(type="text", ng-model="buscador.id", placeholder="Ejemplo: 111")
a.btn.btn-buscador(href="#", ng-click="applySearchFilter()") Buscar
```

listmagazines.jade (quit filter: and add the ng-hide)

```
.col-xlg-25.col-sm-3.col-xs-3.col-xxs-6(ng-repeat="magazine in magazines", ng-hide="magazine.excludedByFilter")
```

controller.js (add this to your app.controller and change the properties)

```
app.controller("revistasController", function($scope,revistas){
  $scope.magazines = revistas.revistasNumeros;

  $scope.applySearchFilter = function() {
    var idFilter = $scope.buscador.id;
    console.log(idFilter);
    var showAll = 0 === idFilter.length;

    angular.forEach($scope.magazines, function(magazine) {
      var id = magazine.id.toString();

      if (showAll) {
        magazine.excludedByFilter = false;
      } else {
        magazine.excludedByFilter = (id.indexOf(idFilter) === -1) 
        || (id.indexOf(idFilter) === -1);
      }
    });
  }
})
```

It works!! :)